# Is it possible to set an Event to the WhatId of SingleEmailMessage?

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage

Is it possible to set Event to the whatId of a SingleEmailMessage? I created a dummy contact with a first name, last name, and email, then inserted it, then set that contact's Id to setTargetObjectId(), then setWhatId() to the event Id...

But I get invalid entity type for whatId, and saw that Event was not in the list of objects in the documentation... But I have seen people trying to put their custom objects in the whatId and people helping them out instead of saying "No, you cannot do that."

So I am wondering if I can use an Event as the whatId, and if so... how do you go about doing that? I am wanting to utilize Event merge fields in this email.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't something you can do. Typical workarounds include creating a custom Task or Event object. You can get pretty elaborate with it, but it really depends on your needs.

Comment: After working with Salesforce for a while, you will no longer expect Event and Task objects to act like other sObjects.

Comment: Ugh... SalesForce........ But I just have a new event created and inserted into the database that I then would like to send email notifications about the event utilizing merge fields... I am not sure creating a custom event will work, unless we limit what users can put in the email as far as event fields go (because every org has their own custom fields on events). Unless I can somehow create a new object in apex that is a clone of the existing event object... but I doubt it.